# Splitting a string with multiple characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following strings:

- Pizza 'PizzaName' this is a certain pizza
- Pizza 'NamePizza' this is a certain pizza
- Pizza 'Hawaii' this is a certain pizza
- Pizza 'Pepperoni' this is a certain pizza
- Pizza is a very nice pizza

So I want the strings containing the `(word)` to be split after this word, but i don't want to split if there is not `(word)` in the string. So I do this:

```
if(strpos($title, "'" !== false)
```

This checks if the string contains the ' character. But now I have to split the string at the second '. Now I tried explode, but that gives me multiple variables in the array. I want there to be:

1. name
2. the substring

How can I do this? Is there a way to give the explode a variable to only split it after the second `'` character?

EDIT: Sorry here is the result I want:

1. Pizza 'PizzaName' -> NAME
2. this is a certain pizza -> SUBSTRING

---

1. Pizza 'NamePizza'
2. this is a certain pizza

---

1. Pizza 'Hawaii'
2. this is a certain pizza

Comment: What do you want the output to be if the (word) isn't there (no splitting). Everything under the name variable?

Comment: why not just use `explode()` on `'`?

Comment: I think an example output from some of those pizza examples would be helpful

Comment: So the explode on the quote will return 3 parts, and you only need 2... so forget about the first one then, and keep the two others. Why is that not good enough?

Comment: @HuubS Many of us can offer you a professional-grade answer, but first you will need to make your question crystal clear.  Please show your best coding attempt and your exact desired output from your sample input.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have edited my main post with clarification of what I want as result, sorry for not having that in the first place.

Comment: @HuubS My StackOverflow principles prohibit me from upvoting your question unless you provide your best coding attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_split()` will ONLY split the string (on the space between the two desired substrings) if there are two single quotes in the string.

```
[^']+     #match 1 or more non-single-quote characters
'         #match single quote
[^']+     #match 1 or more non-single-quote characters
'         #match single quote
\K        #forget previously matched characters and then match space
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mp2Pg)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZDIj7/2))

```
$strings = [
    "Pizza 'PizzaName' this is a certain pizza",
    "Pizza 'NamePizza' this is a certain pizza",
    "Pizza 'Hawaii' this is a certain pizza",
    "Pizza 'Pepperoni' this is a certain pizza",
    "Pizza is a very nice pizza"
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    print_r(preg_split("~[^']+'[^']+'\K ~", $string));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pizza 'PizzaName'
    [1] => this is a certain pizza
)
Array
(
    [0] => Pizza 'NamePizza'
    [1] => this is a certain pizza
)
Array
(
    [0] => Pizza 'Hawaii'
    [1] => this is a certain pizza
)
Array
(
    [0] => Pizza 'Pepperoni'
    [1] => this is a certain pizza
)
Array
(
    [0] => Pizza is a very nice pizza
)
```

To see over 100 more examples of using the awesomeness of `\K`, [here are some of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2943403%20%5Bregex%5D%20%5CK).

Comment: Thanks this is the most clean answer. Thanks everyone for all the other answers

Comment: Be careful not to upvote incorrect answers, not every posted answer is "helpful".  Check the outcome first.  Upvoting incorrect answers will mislead future researchers and undermine appropriately downvoted content.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, I thought these answers would be also good, but I see there are small errors. I don't think I can change my upvote anymore, at least it doesn't let me. Again, sorry for that, I should've tested it better before I upvoted

Comment: @HuubS You can change your vote after a post has been edited.

Comment: @HuubS if/when the answers are corrected, I will encourage you to reconsider your vote.  After all, I'm not trying to "keep anyone down", I am trying to keep StackOverflow great.